# ERROR webdriver: Request failed with status 404 due to invalid session id: invalid session id

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webdriver-io

I am currently creating a set of tests for checking a medical website web application.

When I try to click on the following element  ***"liste_deroulante_en_qualite_specialiste"***
which is a dropdownlist.

```
 get liste_deroulante_en_qualite_specialiste(){
        return $("//crust-disciplines-exercees/descendant:: span[3]")
    }
```

I use it in this function.

```
async remplir_champ_en_qualites_specialiste(){
        await browser.takeScreenshot();
        await this.liste_deroulante_en_qualite_specialiste.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth", block: "end", inline: "nearest" });
        await this.liste_deroulante_en_qualite_specialiste.waitForDisplayed({ timeout: 10000 });
        await this.liste_deroulante_en_qualite_specialiste.click();
        await browser.takeScreenshot();
```

I got the following error from     ***await this.liste_deroulante_en_qualite_specialiste.scrollIntoView***.

```
 2024-01-29T14:46:10.131Z ERROR webdriver: Request failed with status 404 due to invalid session id: invalid session id
[0-0] /home/felix/Bureau/cnomtestauto/node_modules/webdriver/build/utils.js:198
[0-0]     return new CustomRequestError(body, requestOptions);
[0-0]            ^
[0-0] 
[0-0] invalid session id: invalid session id
```

I am currently using webdriver.io 7.34.0. and npm 10.2.2.
I check a similar question on stack but it did not help me.